# How to generate date payment date

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on an estate management application. I have a `payment` table with columns

```
accountId, startPaymentDate, NextPaymentDate, EndPaymentDate, CurrentPaymentDate
```

The challenge I have is generating the `NextPaymentDate`.

This `NextPaymentDate` is generated immediately after the `CurrentPaymentDate` and it is monthly. For instance, if current payment date is 1-04-2017, it should update the table on the next row with `accountId` and `NextPaymentDate` as 1-05-2017.

Thanks

Comment: Okay, so which bit of that are you finding difficult? Do you just need to add a month to `CurrentPaymentDate`?

Comment: i need to get the NextPaymentDate from the CurrentPaymentDate

Comment: So it sounds like you just need to add a month, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `CurrentPaymentDate`'s data type is `DateTime` and the date format you are using is dd/MM/yyyy you should just be able to use the following:

```
NextPaymentDate = CurrentPaymentDate.AddMonths(1);
```

Comment: thanks. From your view i had an idea on how to solve the problem. Just had to use the DATEADD function to add one month to the currentPaymentDate to get the nextPaymentdate.